# for loop in UNIX Script is not working

Tags: shell, unix

```
for i in `cat ${DIR}/${INDICATOR_FLIST}`
do
X=`ls $i|wc -l`
echo $X
echo $X>>txt.txt
done
```

I have a code like this to check if file is present in a directory or not 
but this is not working and gives error like this:

```
not foundtage001/dev/BadFiles/RFM_DW/test_dir/sales_crdt/XYZ.txt
```

You can see there is no space between not found and file path.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific what you mean by "unix script"? What shell are you using, as I guess this is a shell script?

Comment: What are the values of `$DIR` and `$INDICATOR_FLIST`? Does the argument to `cat` exist? Please include a sample of this file.

Comment: Is there any chance that the file `${INDICATOR_FLIST}` came from a Windows machine and has CRLF line endings?  The error message looks scrambled as if that might be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
I have a code like this to check if file is present in a directory or not ...
```

It seems that you're trying to read a list of files from `${DIR}/${INDICATOR_FLIST}` and then trying to determine if those *actually* exist.  The main problem is:

- You're trying to parse `ls` in order to figure whether the file exists.

This is what results in the sort of output that you see; mix of `stderr` and `stdout`.  Use the `test` operator instead as given below.

The following would give tell you whether the file exists or not:

```
while read line; do
  [ -e "${line}" ] && echo "${line} exists" || echo "${line} does not exist";
done < ${DIR}/${INDICATOR_FLIST}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your file `${INDICATOR_FLIST}` has CRLF line terminators (DOS-style). You need to strip out the CR characters, as Unix convention is for LF-only line terminators.

You can tell this by the way "not found" is printed at the start of the line. The immediately preceding character (the last char of the filename) is a CR, which sends the cursor back to the start of the line.

Find a dos2unix utility, or run `tr -d \\015` over it (this deletes all CR's indiscriminately).

Answer (score 0):

maybe the location of your file isn't ok.
take this example

```
m:~ tr$ echo "1 2 3 4 5" > file.txt
m:~ tr$ cat file.txt 
1 2 3 4 5
m:~ tr$ for i in `cat file.txt`;do echo $i ;done
1
2
3
4
5
m:~ tr$
```

you could write the file before "for" and maybe check if the file exists:

```
echo "location : ${DIR}/${INDICATOR_FLIST}"
if [ -e ${DIR}/${INDICATOR_FLIST} ];then echo "file exists ";else echo "file was not found";fi

for i in `cat ${DIR}/${INDICATOR_FLIST}`;
do
let "X=`ls $i|wc -l`";
echo $X;
echo $X>>txt.txt;
done
```

Comment: X=`ls file1.txt|wc -l` echo $X  gives 1 but this is not working in for loop , ihave tried it with more also and its working , but i want to use cat as file lis is long. My file path is correct i have tested it.

Comment: also note that X=`ls $i|wc -l`; does not properly work and  you should try with let "X=`ls $i|wc -l`"

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax is:

```
for i in `cat data-file`
do
    echo $I
done
```

which you are following, therefore the problem must be in the specification of `$DIR` and `$INDICATOR_LIST` so therefore double check the location of your file.